# xmlhttprequest javascript - where do i place my json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest, localhost

Ive got this code in my script tag at my index file

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","images.json",true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    parsedJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseTEXT);
    console.log(parsedJSON["frames"]["turn.png"]["rotated"]);
};
```

Ive executed it through my localhost on node.js
however it keeps coming up with 404 not found.
now i dont now where to put the file at.
in developer tools it shows that its been seached for at http://localhost:2000/images.json
i do not now where or how to place it in the local host, can anyone help
sorry for broken english.

Comment: We can't know how (or even if) your web server is programmed to resolve the path `/images.json`.

Comment: Case matters `responseText`

Comment: Your file would most likely be placed in the same directory as your HTML page with that path you are using. Do you know how references to css/js files works? It is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

#### If you're using [Express](http://expressjs.com)...

Try creating a folder called `public` in the same folder as the file you execute with Node. Then, just pass that folder name to the [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) middleware like this:

```js
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

If you put `images.json` into the `public` folder now, `express.static` will find it and send it to your browser when the file is requested by your script.

And, as epascarello pointed out, JavaScript is case-sensitive. You'll want to change `responseTEXT` to `responseText`.